# Conservative rebar dowel hole sizing and embedment depth

Tags: civil-engineering, reinforced-concrete, epoxy

My question concerns the hole sizing and embedment depth of post installed rebar which is secured with epoxy mortar into a hole in a reinforced concrete slab.

[image]

**Hole diameter sizing**

My assumption #1 is that the minimum and maximum size of the hole depends on the minimum and maximum thickness of the epoxy mortar. Playing around with the [Adhesive Anchor Volume Calculator](https://www.hilti.com/content/hilti/W1/US/en/engineering/technical-information/volume-calculator.html#nav/close) on the Hilti website suggests the following hole sizes:

```
+----------------+----------------+
| Rebar diameter |   Hole size    |
+----------------+----------------+
| 10 mm          | 9/16" (14 mm)  |
| 15 mm          | 3/4" (19 mm)   |
| 20 mm          | 1" (25 mm)     |
| 25 mm          | 1 1/4" (32 mm) |
| 30 mm          | 1 1/2" (38 mm) |
+----------------+----------------+
```

For the purposes of this example consider [HIT-HY 200 Injection Mortar](https://www.hilti.com/content/hilti/W1/US/en/products/catalog-editorials/anchors/products-anchoring-hy200a.html).

**Question 1** - what deviation from these hole sizes is permitted? If a 16 mm hole is accidentally drilled then can the 10 mm rebar still be used with full strength?

**Hole depth sizing**

My assumption #2 is that the required embedment depth of a rebar dowel depends on the bond strength of the epoxy mortar  and the load that the rebar is required to carry.

Conservatively consider that M10 rebar is required to have a pull-out resistance equal to the force that would yield it at 500 N/mm².

Rebar area $= π \times 5^2 = 78.5 \text{ mm}^2$

Rebar circumference $ = 2 π \times 5 = 31.4 \text{ mm}^2$

Conservative pull-out force $= 500 \text{ N/mm}^2 \times 78.5 \text{ mm}^2 = 39.25 \text{ kN}$

For C25/30 concrete the design bond strength of HIT-HY 200 Injection Mortar for any rebar diameter [is given by](https://www.hilti.co.uk/medias/sys_master/documents/h6b/9115979317278/Technical-Application-Document-for-HIT-HY-200-injection-mortar-Approval-document-ASSET-DOC-2926002.pdf) $2.7\,\text{N}/\text{mm}^2$

[image]

Bond-strength per mm of M10 rebar $= 2.7 \times 31.4 = 84.78 \text{ N/mm}$

Required embedment depth $= 39250 \text{ N} ÷ 84.78 \text{ N/mm} = 463 \text{ mm}$

**Question 2** - Is this a conservative methodology for determining the required embedment depth? Will an embedment depth of 463 mm provide full strength in the case of M10 rebar secured with HIT-HY 200 Injection Mortar in C25/30 concrete?

Comment: related (not duplicate) https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/28849/correct-sizing-of-fastener-for-console